# how to get the index of value in drop down in javascript?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown list on my aspx page. I want to mannually set the selected value which in exist in the dropdown list. this value i am getting in var. i want to set this value as selected value when page get initialize. I want this in javascript. is there any property for dropdown as ddp.SelectedValue='40'..? here I don't know the index of 40 in the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`selectedIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a property of HTMLSelectElement so you can do the following:

```
<select id="foo"><option>Zero<option>One<option>Two</select>
<script>
document.getElementById('foo').selectedIndex = 1;  // Selects option "One"
</script>
```

And given an OPTION element, you can get its index using the `index` property:

```
<select><option>Zero<option id="bar">One<option>Two</select>
<script>
alert(document.getElementById('bar').index);  // alerts "1"
</script>
```

Comment: no, i want to get the index of 40 as per my example. How to get it?

Comment: @Lalit, I'm not sure I understand, but I updated the post to explain how to go from an option to its index.  Given the string "40", do you want the index of the option with that value?  Or given the number 40, do you want the option with that index?

Answer (score 9):

> I want to manually set the selected value

Iterate the `select`'s options list to get the `option` you were interested in and set `selected` on it:

```
var options= document.getElementById('ddp').options;
for (var i= 0; n= options.length; i<n; i++) {
    if (options[i].value==='40') {
        options[i].selected= true;
        break;
    }
}
```

this will select the first option with a matching value. If you have more than one option with the same value, or a multiple-select, you may need different logic.

This:

```
document.getElementById('ddp').value= '40';
```

is specified by HTML5 to do the same, and has worked in most modern browsers for ages, but still fails in IE, unfortunately (even IE9).

Comment: Given the question, this seemed like the correct answer.  Perhaps *not enough jQuery* ;-) ps, the latter method works in the IE 10 previews.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery 1.6.2.min.js" />
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(function() {
        quickSelect();
        // Handler for .ready() called.
    });
    function quickSelect() {
        var bnd = "40";
        if (bnd != "") {
            $("#ddp option[value='" + bnd + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    }
</script>
```